# What is the difference between `isomorphic-fetch` and `isomorphic-unfetch` npm packages

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, nestjs, server-side-rendering

I see both are used for SSR. So what's the difference? Apart from isomorphic-fetch [being older and slightly larger gzipped package](https://www.npmtrends.com/isomorphic-fetch-vs-isomorphic-unfetch).

Links:

[Isomorphic Unfetch](https://github.com/developit/unfetch)

[Isomorphic Fetch](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch)

Comment: It's useful to either include links or at least the *names* in the body of the question. I cannot copy the names easily from the title, in order to check out what those even are, since the title is a clickable link.

Comment: The main difference is that they appear to be written by two different people

Comment: @VLAZ added links.

Comment: Neither of these comments were useful.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [isomorphic-fetch](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch) is built on top of [whatwg-fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch) and [isomorphic-unfetch](https://github.com/developit/unfetch/tree/master/packages/isomorphic-unfetch) is built on top of [unfetch](https://github.com/developit/unfetch). What both of them are doing is switching between [node-fetch](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch) and the other package for client and server.

**So their difference is only in the client and the question reduces to:** What's the difference between [whatwg-fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch) and [unfetch](https://github.com/developit/unfetch)?

The [whatwg-fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch) package is an almost complete polyfill for fetch API, but the [unfetch](https://github.com/developit/unfetch) is built with "bundle size" as the first priority in mind (like the other packages written by [Jason Miller](https://github.com/developit) such as [preact](https://github.com/preactjs/preact)). The [unfetch](https://github.com/developit/unfetch) only supports a subset of the full fetch API. However, it's great if you just need simple requests in your application.

A good strategy for new applications is to use [unfetch](https://github.com/developit/unfetch) at first, and replace it with [whatwg-fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch) if you need any feature (such as [streaming](https://web.dev/fetch-upload-streaming/)) which is not supported in [unfetch](https://github.com/developit/unfetch).